Any way to get pid from x$ksuse (v$session) without hitting x$ksupr (v$process)?
Does anyone know of a way to get the PID (x$ksupr.indx => v$process.pid) of an Oracle session from any other table than x$ksupr itself?
As of 19c, at least, the only column available to us from session info to use to join to process info is x$ksuse.ksusepro => v$session.paddr. But x$ksupr.addr is not indexed (surprisingly), so this join requires a full array scan of x$ksupr - potentially tens of thousands of entries. If that's something we have to do at a high frequency that burns up unnecessary CPU.
Oracle does, however, index x$ksupr.indx (pid). So, if we could find out the pid first, based on something in some other x$ table, we could hit the process table on an indexed column, which is 1000x faster than scanning the whole array.
I have so far been unable to find the pid anywhere else. Hoping someone else may have.

Please do not close just because it sounds hard. This is a programming question, not an administration question. It's for a monitoring tool I've written as a developer. It does, however, require knowledge of internals.

Since version 21, the PID can also be found with SYS_CONTEXT: SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'PID') FROM DUAL; However, that is only the PID for the current session, and perhaps SYS_CONTEXT is simply a wrapper around the same V$ tables you already know about. But it might be worth tracing or debugging SYS_CONTEXT. (PS - I also hate how often programming questions here are closed and migrated to DBA.se.)

I found a solution. While there is no known way to find pid outside of the process table, it can be calculated from the process address (x$ksuse.ksusepro / v$session.paddr) as that points to the location in the process array, and there is a relationship between memory location and pid.
Oracle allocates SGA memory for the process (x$ksupr/v$process) array in one, two (most frequently) or at most up to 6 allocation segments (that's the highest I found, at least). This won't change during the lifetime of the instance, so represents a stable structure we can use.
Within each memory allocation segment the pids are assigned sequentially following a fixed interleaving interval (they are typically allocated round-robin to the segments, creating a fixed and reliable pattern - in the most common arrangement, odd number pids are assigned to one segment in ascending order through memory space, and even number pids likewise to the second segment, or vice-versa, but the pattern can vary from instance to instance).
Therefore, we can use SQL one time up front for an instance to analyze the pattern and compute the memory segment start/end and pid/addr intervals for each segment. That need not be repeated ever again for the life of the monitoring session.
We can store that in a PL/SQL nested table that is then used for individual translations of paddr to pid using simple math from the segment start position. Once we have calculated pid, we can do a lightning-fast lookup on x$ksupr/v$process using the indexed column x$ksuspr.indx / v$process.pid. This can be done many thousands of times in high frequency (if needed) with very little CPU footprint.
Proof of concept:
DECLARE
  var_spid integer;
  var_ts timestamp with time zone;
  var_success pls_integer := 0;
  var_failed pls_integer := 0;
 
  TYPE mem_segments_rectype IS RECORD (indx_start integer,
                                       addr_start_decimal integer,
                                       addr_end_decimal integer,
                                       indx_diff integer,
                                       addr_diff integer);
  TYPE mem_segment_tabtype IS TABLE OF mem_segments_rectype;
  tab_mem_segments mem_segment_tabtype;
  
  FUNCTION fl_paddr_to_pid (in_paddr raw)
    RETURN integer
  AS
    var_paddr_decimal integer := TO_NUMBER(in_paddr,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    lvar_pid integer;
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN tab_mem_segments.FIRST .. tab_mem_segments.LAST
    LOOP
      IF var_paddr_decimal >= tab_mem_segments(i).addr_start_decimal AND
         var_paddr_decimal < tab_mem_segments(i).addr_end_decimal
      THEN
        lvar_pid := (((var_paddr_decimal - tab_mem_segments(i).addr_start_decimal) / tab_mem_segments(i).addr_diff ) * tab_mem_segments(i).indx_diff) + tab_mem_segments(i).indx_start;
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    
    RETURN lvar_pid;
  END;
BEGIN
  
  SELECT indx_start,
         TO_NUMBER(addr_start,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') addr_start_decimal,
         TO_NUMBER(NVL(LEAD(addr_start) OVER (ORDER BY addr_start),HEXTORAW('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF')),'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') addr_end_decimal,
         indx_diff,
         addr_diff
    BULK COLLECT INTO tab_mem_segments
    FROM (SELECT last_indx_start indx_start,
                 last_addr_start addr_start,
                 MEDIAN(CASE WHEN indx_diff > 0 THEN indx_diff END) indx_diff,
                 MEDIAN(CASE WHEN indx_diff > 0 THEN addr_diff END) addr_diff
            FROM (SELECT addr,
                         indx,
                         indx_diff,
                         addr_dec,
                         addr_diff,
                         LAST_VALUE(indx_start IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY addr) last_indx_start,
                         LAST_VALUE(addr_start IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY addr) last_addr_start
                    FROM (SELECT addr,
                                 indx,
                                 indx_diff,
                                 addr_dec,
                                 addr_diff,
                                 CASE WHEN (indx_diff > 0) THEN NULL ELSE indx END indx_start,
                                 CASE WHEN (indx_diff > 0) THEN NULL ELSE addr END addr_start
                            FROM (SELECT addr,
                                         indx,
                                         indx - LAG(indx) OVER (ORDER BY addr) indx_diff,
                                         addr_dec,
                                         addr_dec - LAG(addr_dec) OVER (ORDER BY addr) addr_diff
                                    FROM (SELECT addr,indx,TO_NUMBER(addr,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') addr_dec
                                            FROM x$ksupr
                                           WHERE indx >= 3))))
           GROUP BY last_indx_start,
                    last_addr_start);
  
  var_ts := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  
  FOR rec_session IN (SELECT sid,serial#,paddr FROM v$session)
  LOOP
    DECLARE
      var_pid integer;
    BEGIN
      var_pid := fl_paddr_to_pid(rec_session.paddr);
      
      SELECT ksuprpid
        INTO var_spid
        FROM x$ksupr
       WHERE indx = var_pid
         AND addr = rec_session.paddr;
       
      var_success := var_success + 1;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        var_failed := var_failed + 1;

        SELECT MAX(ksuprpid)
          INTO var_spid
          FROM x$ksupr
         WHERE addr = rec_session.paddr;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  
  dbms_output.put_line('DATAOUT: '||TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - var_ts));
  dbms_output.put_line('DATAOUT: Success = '||var_success||', Failure = '||var_failed);
END;

Output:
DATAOUT: +000000000 00:00:00.005646000
DATAOUT: Success = 266, Failure = 1

Versus lookup on addr each time:
DATAOUT: +000000000 00:00:00.506319000

The hack above improved lookup speed (and reduced CPU usage) by 100x. Hopefully someday soon Oracle will help out and actually index addr. I tested this on a few thousand databases. It works on all versions from 10.1 upwards.

I think I was overthinking this. Since the paddr-pid relationship is fixed at instance start, the entire mapping can simply be loaded into an associative array once up front, then used for the lifetime of the session to translate paddr to pid. This achieves the same performance, but is a lot simpler / more elegant than trying to play memory math (though my previous answer does work):
DECLARE
  TYPE ksupr_map_tabtype IS TABLE OF integer INDEX BY varchar2(16);
  tab_ksupr_map ksupr_map_tabtype;
  
  var_spid integer;
  var_ts timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_map IN (SELECT RAWTOHEX(addr) addr_hex,indx FROM x$ksupr)
  LOOP
    tab_ksupr_map(rec_map.addr_hex) := rec_map.indx;
  END LOOP;

  var_ts := SYSTIMESTAMP;

  FOR rec_session IN (SELECT sid,serial#,paddr FROM v$session)
  LOOP
    SELECT ksuprpid
      INTO var_spid
      FROM x$ksupr
     WHERE indx = tab_ksupr_map(RAWTOHEX(rec_session.paddr));
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('DATAOUT: '||TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - var_ts));
END;

Output:
DATAOUT: +000000000 00:00:00.003333000

